# Confused by the adjective "durcheinander"

Tags: meaning

Here is a sentence:

> Völlig durcheinander eilte er zu seinem Wagen.

I don't really get what part of speech "durcheinander" belongs to in this specific context. To my knowledge, it's an adjective that is predominantly used predicatively and seldomly as an attribute to a noun. But here I'm totally at a loss.

Comment: That means you're *völlig durcheinander* ;)

Answer (score 1):

*Durcheinander* isn't an adjective but an adverb meaning *in shambles*. The adverbial *völlig durcheinander* means *Utterly in shambles*.

> Völlig durcheinander eilte er zu seinem Wagen.

*Utterly in shambles, he skeltered to his car.*

Answer (score 1):

Calling it an adjective or an adverb or an adcopula or whatever doesn't explain anything and doesn't help. If it is called an adjective (as the Duden grammar 2016 does in such cases), then it still cannot be inflected (like an adverb), if it is an adverb then it still expresses a property (like an adjective). German grammars differ a lot as to what they do with such words, there is no consensus. This is independent of the grammatical construction that it appears in, however.

Maning and function are clear and simple. It expresses a state of a person, so it can be used in predicative function after a copula ("Er ist durcheinander") or as an adjunct in the clause, like in your example. This function is often not called "adverbial", because it doesn't modify the verb, it merely states a property or a state of the subject during the event. The grammatical function may be called "freies Prädikativ".
Examples: "Die Kinder kammen *verdreckt* nach Hause" (exactly parallel: "The children came home dirty"), "Er aß den Apfel *ungewaschen*". Adjectives that have roughly the same meaning and the same use as "durcheinander" are "verdattert, verwirrt". They work exactly the same, they just don't raise questions as to their word class. So who needs word classes :)